# Error con imagenes vectoriales

Tags: android, svg

Tengo arreglos de imagenes vectoriales pero cuando ejecuto el app, esta se trunca, lo que despliega el telefono es "Unfortunately, app has stopped" y lo que muestra el logcat es:

> 03-29 01:28:37.177 3176-3176/matgic.com.matgic E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating 
>                                                                        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v22/$ic_strawberry__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f070023
>   Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid color state list tag gradient

aqui el código:

```
int [] f2={R.drawable.ic_apple, R.drawable.ic_pineapple, R.drawable.ic_strawberry, R.drawable.ic_coconut};
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_strawberry);
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "matgic.com.matgic"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: ahí dice que en el ic_strawberry.xml tienes una etiqueta de color 'un estado' no válido.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del recurso ic_strawberry.xml.

Comment: Sergio en realidad el problema es el contenido, esta llamando un recurso que no existe, esto dentro del vector asset si tienes el .svg agregalo o el .xml @Sergio

Comment: @Jorgesys sobrepasa los caracteres permitidos, en este link pueden verlo https://matgic.000webhostapp.com/ic_strawberry.xml

Comment: Gracias @Sergio ya lo veo, es una strawberry yo lo veo sin problema, que configuración usas en tu build.gradle, si pudes agregarla seria excelente

Comment: listo @Jorgesys

Comment: Tienes que eliminar los gradientes para versiones anteriores a la API 24 @Sergio agregué una solución para crear tu gráfico sin los gradientes y usarlo sin problema.

Comment: @Jorgesys realizaré lo que dices y te comentaré, independientemente de lo que pase, millones de gracias por tu valioso tiempo, eres un crack, saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75281/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-sergio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad [android:fillColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) de un Gradiente es soportada por API 24+ (7.0 o posterior)

> [android:fillColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)  Especifica el color utilizado para completar
>   la ruta. Puede ser un color o, para SDK 24+, una lista de estado de
>   color o un degradado de color (consulte GradientColor y
>   GradientColorItem). Si esta propiedad está animada, cualquier valor
>   establecido por la animación anulará el valor original. No se dibuja
>   ningún relleno de ruta si esta propiedad no está especificada.

Si pruebas tu código en un dispositivo con OS 7.0 o posterior no se tendría ningún problema pero en este caso para que funcione en versiones anteriores agrega en el folder `/drawable` la versión de tu gráfico sin los gradientes, y crea un folder `/drawable-v24` donde agregues el .xml completo con los gradientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El gráfico de `/drawable-v24` sería cargado únicamente para versiones Android 7.0 o posterior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución es comentar o elimina los gradientes, por ejemplo:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="651.95"
    android:viewportWidth="531.48" android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M386.8,30.2c-48.5,0 -76.1,18 -121.1,18s-72.6,-18 -121.1,-18c-87.9,0 -144.7,83.3 -144.7,186 0,92.9 160,350.5 265.7,350.5 112.9,0 265.7,-257.6 265.7,-350.5C531.5,113.5 474.7,30.2 386.8,30.2Z">
        <!--<aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="212457.73219299316"
                android:endY="440836.2612554932"
                android:startX="212457.73219299316"
                android:startY="92857.94223999024" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFFC3A11" android:offset="0.0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFDA0300" android:offset="1.0"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>-->
    </path>
    ...
    ...
```

y usa la propiedad **android:fillColor** del **path** para asignar un color, por ejemplo el color rojo:

```
<path android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:pathData="M386.8,30.2c-48.5,0 -76.1,18 -121.1,18s-72.6,-18 -121.1,-18c-87.9,0 -144.7,83.3 -144.7,186 0,92.9 160,350.5 265.7,350.5 112.9,0 265.7,-257.6 265.7,-350.5C531.5,113.5 474.7,30.2 386.8,30.2Z">
...
...
```

y el color verde para las hojas:

```
   <path android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"  android:pathData="M179.7,1.2c-39,-0.9 -73.5,36.7 -78.1,70 65.4,15.4 111.7,-19.6 111.7,-19.6 -12,26.3 -3,49.5 9.7,81.6 9.7,24.5 6.3,43.5 6.3,43.5S346.7,169.4 327.6,61.8c30,28.2 73.5,37.5 101.7,27.3 -8.5,-24.8 -5.8,-63.8 -47.5,-80C345.9,-4.8 302.8,-4.8 276.2,23.4 249.6,2.1 179.7,1.2 179.7,1.2Z">
   ...
   ...
```

esta versión de tu gráfico se guardaría dentro de `/drawable` para obtener la imagen sin gradientes soportada para versiones anteriores a Android 7.0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

por cierto `aaptOptions`  se debe declarar dentro del bloque `android`, esto en tu `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

}
```

Comment: esa fue la solución, funciona perfectamente, mil gracias hermano, saludos!

Comment: Excelente @Sergio saludos!